# Avoid object variable in RDD operations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I cannot show the code that confuses me since it is not allowed to make it public. I give some examples similar below. I have defined an object `Config` similar to the following:

```
object Config {
  val on: Boolean = System.getProperty("on", "true").toBoolean
}
```

Depending on the value of `Config.on`, for an RDD, different works are done:

```
rdd.map {
  if (Config.on) {
    // do A
  } else {
    // do B
  }
}
```

I am using spark-submit and setting `Config.on` by specifying --driver-java-options. When I set --driver-java-options as "-Don=false", for example,

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options "-Don=false" ...
```

the map function above still executes the A part as if `Config.on` is true. I wonder why this happens.

Comment: Not too sure whether `--driver-java-options` makes it to the worker jvm. Can you try to print it on the worker to see if the system property is being set?

Comment: @ernest_k It seems not. Could you please provide a solution?

Comment: Just by the way, you should be using `"-Don=false"` (hyphen for `-D`)